# How to define the document class parameters?

Tags: formatting, document-classes

I am using this document class for a chapter:

> `\documentclass[runningheads,a4chapter]{llncs}`

How can I define a class so I has the following features:

1. A4 page with 1 inch (or, 2.54 cm) margin on all sides,
2. single column format, 1.5 line spacing with 11 point sized font,
3. Times New Roman

Comment: For (1) use `geometry` package with `margin=1in` as option. For (2), I think that the class supports the `11pt` option. For (3) you can use `newtxtext,newtxmath` which is very simillar to Times.

Comment: Not all document classes have the same options.  See the manual for llncs for what options it supports.